# using lightbox on dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using [HTMLKickStart](https://github.com/joshuagatcke/HTML-KickStart) , there seems to be a problem with dynamically generated links and using them with lightbox.

I had already added the lightbox class but the link still behaves like a regular link:

```
var new_link = $('<a>').attr({'href' : 'php/group_members.php'}).appendTo(new_manage).addClass('lightbox');
```

There was a question before:

[jquery lightbox on dynamic image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226900/jquery-lightbox-on-dynamic-image)

And I tried the following:

```
$(document).find('a.lightbox').lightBox();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working either. Do you have a better idea on how to make this work or do you think this is a problem with the framework that I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the author directly and he gave me this:

```
// lightbox links
    $('a.lightbox').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).fancybox({
            overlayOpacity: 0.2,
            overlayColor: '#000'
        });
    });
```

If anyone is having the same problems with html kickstart just edit the kickstart.js file and search for lightbox links then change it to the code above.